# Showing window on seperate thread works only once

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am using the following code to try and show a wpf window on a separate thread so that the animated gif on it will work while the UI thread of the main window does stuff with data:

```
private Thread tBusy;


private void ShowBusyWindow(string message, double top, double left, double height, double width)
{
    BusySplash busyForm = new BusySplash(message, top, left, height, width)
    busyForm.Show();
}

private void ShowBusy(string message, UIElement container)
{
    if (busy != null) return;

    double top = container.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0)).Y;
    double left = container.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0)).X;
    double width = container.RenderSize.Width;
    double height = container.RenderSize.Height;


    ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(() => ShowBusyWindow(message, top, left, height, width));
    tBusy = new Thread(ts);

    tBusy.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    tBusy.IsBackground = true;
    tBusy.Start();
}

private void HideBusy()
{

    tBusy.Abort();
    tBusy = null;
}
```

I am surrounding the code doing work with the ShowBusy() function at the beginning and the HideBusy() at the end.

But unfortunately ShowBusy() runs once successfully and then throws:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'

What can I do to prevent this error?  I tried executing the `busyForm.Show()` using the busyForm's dispatcher but get the same error.

Comment: Using multiple ui threads in wpf is possible but it's a choice of last resort. It's much more usual to use wpf animation on a spinner on the ui thread. Gather data on a background thread and pass it back to the ui thread for display. Have you considered this approach?

Comment: I have considered it but since most of the data work is pretty much complete I was hoping there would be a quick and dirty way of displaying a busy splash screen without making the data stuff thread friendly since it does interact with the UI a lot. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Never ever call `Thread.Abort()` (unless you are trying to crash out of your app entirely) as it can leave the run-time corrupted and you cannot trust any code to work properly afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

UI work must be offloaded onto the UI thread.

```
private void ShowBusyWindow(string message, double top, double left, double height, double width)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        BusySplash busyForm = new BusySplash(message, top, left, height, width)
        busyForm.Show();
    });
}
```

A few things though:

- You really do not need to create a separate STA thread for your busy indicator. Offload non-ui work onto a Task so that the UI does not get blocked. From there, only make UI updates on the UI thread. It sounds like the reason why your UI is blocking is because you're doing too much on the UI.
- Aborting the Thread to close the Busy indicator is a bit weird. It's much cleaner to simply just call .Close on the control (assuming it's a WPF Window).